# Dynamically recognize missing space mistype and run the correspondent command (without aliases)

Tags: bash, shell

I'd like to know if there's a way to make bash recognize a specific mistype I do sometimes (a missing space) and "fix" the command.
Example: if I type `gitadd` (without the space between `git` and `add`), how can I make bash know that I meant `git add` and run the command?

Of course I could create an alias for that, but I don't want to create aliases for all possible commands - and I want to do it not only for git, but for any command (so `ls-l` becomes `ls -l`, `cd~/somedir` becomes `cd ~/somedir`, and so on).

In a general form, `[existent-command][param]` (without space) becomes `[existent-command] [param]` (with a space between them). Bash recognizes it and run the command.

I really couldn't find a way to do this (except creating lots of aliases). Can bash do it? Do I need some external tool (maybe using another language)?

Comment: You might be able to hack something together in bash, or perhaps in zsh using a command_not_found handler - but it would probably be so slow as to be unusable. Take your 'gitadd' example - your tool would need to figure out where to insert the space, so it would first have to try 'g itadd', then 'gi tadd', and then finally 'git add'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, it's a bit expensive, because you essentially have to try every possible place to insert a space into the "wrong" command and see if that produces a valid command/argument pair. Can `gitadd` be split into

- `g` `itadd`
- `gi` `tadd`
- `git` `add`
- `gita` `dd`
- `gitad` `d`

Worse, there might be *multiple* valid pairs. If I have a command named `gi`, is `gitadd` supposed to be `git add`, or `gi tadd`?

---

For your case, though, if you want to assume that any command *starting* with `git` should be split, you can define `command_not_found_handle` (in `bash` 4 or later) to try the split for your. Add the following to your `.bashrc`:

```
command_not_found_handle () {
    if [[ $1 == git* ]]; then
        git "${1#git}" "${@:2}"
    else
        printf 'bash: %s: command not found\n' "$1" >&2
        return 127
    fi
}
```

If a command like `gitadd` is not found, the function above is called with `gitadd` and its arguments as the function's arguments. `${1#git}` would expand `add` (`gitadd` minus the prefix `git`), then `git` would be called with the appropriate arguments. Otherwise, we duplicate what `bash` would have done ordinarily for an unrecognized command.

Comment: Great! That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I've modified the code suggested above to read command names from my PATH and check for them in a loop (and returns the command exit code after running it). Basically:

```
CMDS=(find files in PATH)
for c in $CMDS do
  if [[ $1 == ${c}* ]]; then
    ${c} "${1#${c}}" "${@:2}"
    return $?
  fi
done
printf 'bash: %s: command not found\n' "$1" >&2
return 127
```

With this, I'm covering a good range of commands and it's working fine. Thanks again!